# Reload table after deleting an item from it with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Using React.Js, I created a delete function to delete an item from a table. the delete is working fine but what I want to do is that after deleting I want the tables to be dynamically updated to show only the items left. Now after the delete I have to refresh manually the page or go to another page and comeback to see the items left after the delete

This is the code built so far :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Select,/*  message, */ Form, Tooltip } from "antd";
import extraitMP3 from "./data";
import { arrayMove, SortableHandle } from "react-sortable-hoc";
import ContainerHeader from "components/ContainerHeader/index";
import { getExtraitMp3, hideMessageUpdate, showUpdateLoader, updateMp3Visibilite } from "appRedux/actions/Comedien";
import { deleteMp3Request } from "../../../appRedux/services/extraitMp3Service"
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { NotificationContainer, NotificationManager } from "react-notifications";
import { userSignOut } from "appRedux/actions/Auth";
import { displayIcon } from '../../../util/Icon.js';
import CircularProgress from "components/CircularProgress";
import { Modal } from "antd";

const extraitMP32 = [extraitMP3];
const confirm = Modal.confirm;
const Option = Select.Option;

const DragHandle = SortableHandle(() =>
  <span className="gx-draggable-icon gx-pt-2">
    <i className="icon icon-menu" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} />
  </span>);

class ListExtrait extends Component {

  onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    this.setState({
      extraitMP3: arrayMove(this.state.extraitMP3, oldIndex, newIndex),

    });
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      extraitMP3: extraitMP32[0],
      nombreMP3: {
        rechercheExtraits: 0,
        recherchePossible: 0,
        extraitFiche: 0,
        extraitFichePossible: '',
        extraitArchives: 0,
        extraitArchivesPossible: '',
      },
      loader: false,

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getExtraitMp3();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState,/* nextProps2,prevState2 */) {
    if (nextProps.extraitMP3 !== prevState.extraitMP3 && nextProps.extraitMP3) {
      return { extraitMP3: nextProps.extraitMP3 };
    }
    else return null;
  }
  showDeleteConfirmation(value, id, index, thisHandler) {
    confirm({
      title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cette audio ?',
      content: '',
      okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'Non',
      onOk() {
        deleteMp3Request(id);
        const { extraitMP3 } = thisHandler.state;
        Object.keys(extraitMP3).splice(index, 1);
        NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
      },
      onCancel() {
      },
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {

      if (!err) {
        this.props.showUpdateLoader();
        this.props.updateMp3Visibilite(values);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {

    const { loader, extraitMP3 } = this.state;
    const selectOptions = new Map([
      [1, "Visible dans la recherche et sur ma fiche"],
      [2, "Visible sur ma fiche uniquement"],
      [3, "Masqué"],
    ]);
    console.log('extraitMP3', extraitMP3)


    function handleChangeSelect(value) {
      console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {loader ? <CircularProgress className="gx-loader-400" /> : Object.keys(extraitMP3).map((ids, index) => {
          return (
            <Card>

              <li key={ids}>
                <Card styleName="gx-card-list icon icon-data-display gx-mr-2 gx-text-blue gx-fs-xl">
                  <div className="gx-media-body">
                    {extraitMP3[ids].Typenom}
                    &nbsp;
                  {extraitMP3[ids].TypeIcon != null &&
                      displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeIcon)
                    }
                  </div>

                  {Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List).map(idJson => {
                    return (
                      <div className="gx-main-content gx-mb-4">
                        <ContainerHeader match={this.props.match} />
                        <div className="gx-contact-item gx-dragndrop-item">

                          <DragHandle />

                          <div className="gx-col gx-job-title ">
                            {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].intitule}
                          </div>

                          {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Icon !== '' &&
                            <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Nom}>
                              {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation1Icon)}
                            </Tooltip>
                          }

                          {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Icon !== '' &&
                            <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Nom}>
                              {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation2Icon)}
                            </Tooltip>
                          }

                          {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Icon !== '' &&
                            <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Nom}>
                              {displayIcon(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].interpretation3Icon)}
                            </Tooltip>
                          }

                          {extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueIcon !== '' &&
                            <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                              <Tooltip title={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueNom}>
                                <i className={`flag flag-24 gx-mr-2 ${extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].langueIcon}`} />
                              </Tooltip>
                            </div>
                          }

                          <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                            <Select
                              showSearch
                              style={{ width: '100%' }}
                              placeholder="Selection la choix de votre numÃ©ro de tÃ©lÃ©phone "
                              optionFilterProp="children"
                              onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                              defaultValue={selectOptions.get(extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].visibilite)}
                              filterOption={(input, Option) => Option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                            >
                              {[...selectOptions].map(([value, label]) => <Option value={value}> {label} </Option>)}
                            </Select>
                          </div>

                          <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                            <i className="icon icon-edit gx-fs-xl gx-text-gris" />
                          </div>

                          <div className="gx-col gx-job-title  gx-d-sm-flex gx-text-truncate gx-px-8">
                            <span className="gx-pointer">
                              <i className="icon icon-trash gx-pointer gx-text-danger gx-fs-xxl"
                                id={extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].id}
                                onClick={e => this.showDeleteConfirmation(e.target.value, extraitMP3[ids].TypeMp3List[idJson].id, index, this)} />
                            </span>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
                  <NotificationContainer />

                  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" labelCol={{ xs: 24, sm: 5 }} wrapperCol={{ xs: 24, sm: 12 }}>
                    Enregistrer
                </Button>
                </Card>
              </li>
            </Card>
          )
        })}</div>
    )
  }
}

const VisibiliteFormMp3 = Form.create()(ListExtrait);

const mapStateToProps = ({ comedien }) => {
  const {
    extraitMP3,
    alertMessageUpdate,
    showMessageUpdate
  } = comedien;
  return {
    extraitMP3,
    alertMessageUpdate,
    showMessageUpdate
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    userSignOut,
    getExtraitMp3,
    hideMessageUpdate,
    showUpdateLoader,
    updateMp3Visibilite
  })(VisibiliteFormMp3);
```

extraitMP3 is an object of objects that's why I used `Object.keys(extraitMP3)`
I didn't know how to update the state correctly.
this is the view :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put your data in state and then change the state. After changing the state the page automatically re-rendered and changed data of your state will be shown.
So in your delete function simply delete your chosen data and give your remaining data to your state.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask questions if I couldn't explain myself clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by calling something like and then just call this from within your delete

```
refreshMp3(){ 
this.setState({getExtraitMp3: !this.state.getExtraitMp3});}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas of React is to make the functionality you ask for simple to implement and it would update automatically. I'm going to abstract a bit from your example. Think about your data in terms of what updates along with the UI. This way we can simplify your component. You have some items that you put in a table. Each item is a row and can be inside an array. We put that array in the state.

```
class ListExtrait extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       rowsForTable: [...],
       somethingElse...
    }
    ...
```

Then in the JSX in the render method you can render the table rows using `map`:

```
rowsForTable.map(item => <div/li/whatever>{item.name or something else}</div>
```

This way whenever an item is gone from `rowsForTable` the component will automatically update it's view and the table rows will be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the function while clicking the delete button say deleteHandler. On that function call the api you have made to delete the item and then after successfull delete again call the api that will show the item from database after certain time interval.

```
Code: 

  import React, { Component } from 'react'

  export default class show_schedule extends Component {
    render() {
      state={

      }
      show_item_after_delete=()=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/api/show_item/`).then(res=>{
          console.log('delete schedule data ',res.data)

        })
        },500)
      }
      deleteHandler=()=>{
        axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/api/delete_item/${id}`).then(res=>{
          console.log(res.data)
        })
        this.show_item_after_delete()
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: It will work but last item will not remove...